# Initializer fails to determine size of character array

Tags: c++, memory, gcc

Whenever I run the code below (Yes that's **all** the code) the compiler gives me an error:

***error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘path’***

What I want to do is copy the contents of argv[0], which is the path of the application as a character array, into the path variable.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int offset = 0;
    int pathSize = 0;
    while(argv[0][pathSize] != '\0')
        pathSize++;

    char path[] = new char[pathSize];
    delete &path;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable length arrays aren't valid in C++?

Comment: @JustinMeiners, Not until C++14

Comment: @JustinMeiners - just to be clear, there are no variable length arrays here.

Comment: @PeteBecker ok i knew they aren't available, but were not sure if this was the problem. I asked for my own learning :)

Comment: @JustinMeiners - a variable length array looks like a local named object with a runtime size: `void f(int i) { int vla[i]; }`. The code here uses `new char[pathSize]`, which allocates from the free store.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was just confused about the array new char[pathSize]; syntax.

Comment: @JustinMeiners - that's the `new` operator.

Comment: @JustinMeiners - sorry, just trying to guess at what needs to be said. `<g>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your error is in the below part of your code:

```
char path[] = new char[pathSize];
delete &path;
```

Change it to...

```
char *path = new char[pathSize];
delete[] path;
```

Comment: Honestly, the proper advice is to use `std::string` instead of this problematic `new` and `delete` nonsense.

Comment: I will need to convert the string to character array anyways because I  am preparing the path to send to another function which requires a character array.

Answer (score 4):

First, `char path[]` should be `char* path`. Second, its `delete[] path;`. If you `new[]` you `delete[]` if you `new` you `delete`.

There is an extension for gcc (which is not standard mind you) which allows you to do this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int size = 34;
    char path[size];

    return 0;
}
```

However this will work only in gcc as this is a gcc extension.

Comment: Yeah sorry. It's some left-over from what I had first.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dynamic array.

```
char* path = new char[pathSize];
```

and as others have mentioned delete is only needed for new, therefore you do need it, but the way your code was written is not how you would normally want to use delete